# Writing embedded list to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a method in a Python app to write a list of records to a CSV file.  Each record is a "football player", which is really just a dictionary.  But one of the dictionary items contains a list of weekly scores.  I want to write out to CSV a record for each player, and then flatten the list of scores and write that out, too.

My code:

```
def write_csv_file(filename, year, list_of_players):
    print str(datetime.now()) + ' Writing file {0}'.format(OUTPUT_CSV_PATH + filename + '.csv')
    print list_of_players
    with open(OUTPUT_CSV_PATH + filename + '.csv', 'w+') as f:

        writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator = '\n')

        writer.writerow(['YEAR', 'FILENAME', 'PLAYER_KEY', 'PLAYER_NAME', 'SEASON_TOTAL', 'CALCULATED_SEASON_TOTAL', 'MEAN', 'MEDIAN', 'STD_DEVIATION', 'CV',
            'WK1', 'WK2', 'WK3', 'WK4', 'WK5', 'WK6', 'WK7', 'WK8', 'WK9', 'WK10', 'WK11', 'WK12', 'WK13', 'WK14', 'WK15', 'WK16'])
        for item in list_of_players:
            writer.writerow([year, filename, item['player_key'], item['player_name'], item['season_total'],
                item['calculated_season_total'], item['mean'], item['median'], item['std_deviation'], item['coefficient_of_variation'],
                #item['performance_score'],
                item['scores'][0],
                item['scores'][1],
                item['scores'][2],
                item['scores'][3],
                item['scores'][4],
                item['scores'][5],
                item['scores'][6],
                item['scores'][7],
                item['scores'][8],
                item['scores'][9],
                item['scores'][10],
                item['scores'][11],
                item['scores'][12],
                item['scores'][13],
                item['scores'][14],
                item['scores'][15]
                ])
```

It's the handling of `item['scores']` that I'm sure there's a better way.  I tried getting a list comprehension to work but never could get it going.

How can I do this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick win for readability would be to rename `item` to `player`.  Another improvement would be to put each field on its own line, since the long lines vastly exceed the [79-character limit suggested by PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

For the 16 scores, you can write…

```
writer.writerow([
    'YEAR',
    'FILENAME',
    'PLAYER_KEY',
    'PLAYER_NAME',
    'SEASON_TOTAL',
    'CALCULATED_SEASON_TOTAL',
    'MEAN',
    'MEDIAN',
    'STD_DEVIATION',
    'CV'
] + ['WK{0}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(16)])

for player in list_of_players:
    writer.writerow([
        year,
        filename,
        player['player_key'],
        player['player_name'],
        player['season_total'],
        player['calculated_season_total'],
        player['mean'],
        player['median'],
        player['std_deviation'],
        player['coefficient_of_variation']
    ] + player['scores'])
```

Comment: Perfect!  I had to do `'WK{0}'.format(i)` instead, but that cleaned it up nice.  Also modded to `['WK{0}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(list_of_players[0]['scores'])+1)])` to ultimately deal with a variable number of weeks as the season progresses.  Thanks!

Comment: On further thought, I would rewrite the `range()` because the 17 is unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.format` for `datetime.now()` as well. It will automatically run the `str` call just by being included. Also you don't need to pass numbers into `{}`. If you're just using each parameter once, then you can just pass them in order. I'd also recommend creating the filepath in advance of this `print` call, since you'll need it later anyway.

```
def write_csv_file(filename, year, list_of_players):
    filepath = OUTPUT_CSV_PATH + filename + '.csv'
    print '{} Writing file {}'.format(datetime.now(), filepath)
```

Also you should import the `os` module to create file paths. Specifically, the `os.path.join` function will create OS appropriate paths from string arguments, which makes it easier to manage path strings.

```
    filepath = os.path.join(OUTPUT_CSV_PATH, filename + '.csv')
```

Even just to log a list, you might want to use `str.join`. You can print a list neater using one of these:

```
print ', '.join(list_of_players)
print '\n'.join(list_of_players)
```

`str.join` will print a long string with each element of a list joined by the string its called on. So the first example above prints all the elements of your list as a comma separated string, while the second separates them with newlines. These are more readable when printed out like this.

Also I don't like the long name `list_of_players` when just `players` communicates the same idea. It's clearly multiple players, and since you loop over it people can easily see it's a list, no need to use the name to indicate that.